# Storage seems to be filling up by itself in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, storage

My hard drive appears to be filling itself up by itself. Every time I delete files, it immediately fills up. I do not have back up enabled either. I don't even download much. I mostly stream. The only thing that autodownloads is variety.

Comment: What is the message that says the drive is filling up? The only way is to take a look (with tools like baobab, du, df) maybe every few hours or days and see what gets bigger. What drives are full/filling, and what directories does baobab say keep getting bigger?

Answer (score 1):

Should use `baobab` (disk usage analyzer) to check out what's taking up all the space, it does nice visual representations of folders & their relative sizes too. May have to run as root (sudo) in case there are lots of files hidden from your user.

But sometimes web browsers could eat up space with their profiles or caches, or downloaded .deb files might be kept in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` (an `apt-get clean` should clear them, or use `rm` yourself)